# How to run a function in Swift when the iPhone or iPad sleeps?

Tags: swift, sleep-mode

I'm working on an app where you log down what you eat. I have my app set to save the information to my MySQL server every time I close the view (like go back a step in the Navbar) or press the home button. How can I run my saving function down when you turn off the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the function in `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillResignActive` in your `AppDelegate` depending on which one you require. `applicationWillResignActive` if you want to save even if the app is interrupted by for example a phone call